# Make cloned png draggable Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first time using javascript. I'm trying to make this image draggable. Right now, the original png is draggable. I click a button to clone the image, which works, but the clone isn't draggable. Please help! Thanks so much for your time.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});




$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("body").append($("section:first").clone().addClass('drag(event)'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kOOsSXe.jpg">
</div>

<section class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RWdfFRO.png" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="130" draggable="true"> </section>

<button>Tank Man</button>
```

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because you havent made it draggable by using this piece of code

$( ".draggable" ).draggable();

So i would suggest you to modify your code like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

 var element=$("section:first").clone().addClass('drag(event)');       
$("body").append(element);
element.draggable();
 });
```